# R get rows between different dates where one column has date and another column has a number corresponding to +/- day window

Tags: r, date, filtering

I have a table that looks like so

```
dat <- data.frame(id = c(rep(1234, 8)), code = c(20600, 24567, 20600, 25067, 234456, 23456, 20600, 23356),
              date = c('04-04-2019','05-05-2019', '04-04-2019', '04-04-2019', '12-26-2019', '04-10-2019', 
                       '04-30-2019', '11-14-2019'), days=c(10,90,10,90,30,23,10,30))
```

I am essentially interested in keeping only the rows that fall within the window of (date - days) and (date + days) *specifically* for windows of code 20600 which would look something like so:

```
dat1 <- data.frame(id = c(rep(1234, 5)), code = c(20600, 20600, 25067,23456, 20600),
                   date = c('04-04-2019','04-04-2019', '04-04-2019', '04-10-2019', 
                            '04-30-2019'), days=c(10,10,90,23,10))
```

is there any way to do this in R? This is just a small subset on a larger dataset, so I'd like to find a way to apply a solution that would facilitate the process once I go large scale. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would keep 20 days on either side of 4-15-2019:

```
dat <- data.frame(id = c(rep(1234, 8)), code = c(20600, 24567, 20600, 25067, 234456, 23456, 20600, 23356),
                  date = c('04-04-2019','05-05-2019', '04-04-2019', '04-04-2019', '12-26-2019', '04-10-2019', 
                           '04-30-2019', '11-14-2019'), days=c(10,90,10,90,30,23,10,30))

dat <- dat %>% 
  mutate(date = lubridate::mdy(date)) %>% 
  filter(date %in% seq((mdy("04-15-2019")-20), (mdy("04-15-2019")+20), by=1))

dat
#     id  code       date days
# 1 1234 20600 2019-04-04   10
# 2 1234 24567 2019-05-05   90
# 3 1234 20600 2019-04-04   10
# 4 1234 25067 2019-04-04   90
# 5 1234 23456 2019-04-10   23
# 6 1234 20600 2019-04-30   10
```